# Family of clopen with FIP in a compact space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a non-empty family of non-empty clopen subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property. It's true that $\bigcap\mathcal{F}$ has non-empty interior?

Comment: It looks like the title and body ask different things. You don't mention the finite intersection property in the question body.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $X = \{ 0 \} \cup \{ \frac{1}{k} : k \geq 1 \}$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$), and for each $n$ define $F_n = \{ 0 \} \cup \{ \frac{1}{k} : k \geq n \}$.